# ResolveEndpointFailedException: "There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint." when creating endpoint with the endpoint DSL

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am migrating from Camel 2 to Camel 3 and I'm eager to use the Endpoint DSL described [here](https://camel.apache.org/blog/Camel3-Whatsnew/), however I'm running into an issue when migrating my endpoints.

I used to have a route writing to a RabbitMQ queue like this:

```
.toD("rabbitmq:$vhost?connectionFactory=#customConnectionFactory&queue=$responseQueueName&autoDelete=false&routingKey=$responseQueueName&bridgeEndpoint=true")
```

Which I migrated to

```
.toD(
    rabbitmq(vhost)
    .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
    .queue(responseQueueName)
    .autoDelete(false)
    .routingKey(responseQueueName)
    .bridgeEndpoint(true)
```

However, when creating the endpoint, Camel also adds a `hash` parameter that cannot be set to the endpoint, resulting in the following exception:

> Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://MYVHOST?autoDelete=false&bridgeEndpoint=true&hash=753a744c&queue=MYQUEUENAME&routingKey=MYQUEUENAME due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{hash=753a744c}]

My endpoint syntax is correct, AFAIK, because I'm using an endpoint created the same way in the `from` clause of my route.

Comment: Looks like a bug, you are welcome to create Jira issue. As a workaround you can use `.connectionFactory("#customConnectionFactory")`

Comment: The issue is not with the connection factory itself, but rather with `toD` not accepting the hash parameter.

Comment: Ah yeah looks like its when you refer to an connection factory instance then the uri builder generates this via a hash placeholder

Comment: Thanks I have reproduced the issue and logged a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the output endpoint being specified with `toD`, switching it to a regular `to` solved the issue.